# SQL how to update table based name tablename from other table column

Tags: sql-server, tablename

I need to update a value in several tables, when migrating a production database to a test environment. The name of the tables can be found in another table. How can I do this?

I mean:

```
for each value$ in select replace(tablename,' ','') from table1

update value$ set replace(column1,'A','B')
```

It looks like a nested SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build some dynamic sql for this. I prefer to build it in one go and execute as a whole:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '' 
select @sql += '
    update ' + QUOTENAME(replace(tablename,' ','')) + ' 
        set column1 = replace(column1,''A'',''B'')'      
from table1

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: I think you'll just need `set column1 = replace(column1, ''A'', ''B'')` - currently missing the column name you're setting, and escaping the single quotes around the string values.

Comment: @Bridge: Fixed - taa - just copied the actual update from the OP.

Comment: Also you could use QUOTENAME to escape the table name for you (e.g. if it had single quotes/square brackets in the table name it should do it properly):  `...  select @sql += 'update ' + QUOTENAME(replace(tablename,' ','')) + ' set ...` etc.